# Match Computed Value

Tags: vue.js

I’m trying to conditionally validate a value that returns in computed. When the computed value is ready, I would like to set it as a data value.

Thereafter use this data value in method that match the content of the string. To check if the url has audio file extension such as mp3, Wave. However, I can’t get a match even though I explicitely write e.g. “mp3” or “wave” in the string.

```
<template>
  <div>
<p>Hello There</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Musician",
  data() {
    return {
      string: this.audioLink /*logs e.g. www.popsongs.com/groovy.mp3 */
      findings: ''
    }
  },

  computed: {
    hasAudioFile() {
      return this.audioLink;
    }
  },

  mounted() {
      this.runMatch();
  },

  methods : {
      runMatch: function() {
         let urlPath = this.audioLink;
         this.findings = urlPath.match(/mp3|wave/gi);

         if(this.findings === 'mp3') return console.log('This is a MP3 file');
         else if (this.findings === 'wave') return console.log('This is a Wave file');
         else return console.log('No sound files found'); 

/* The example url has a .mp3, but I still get the final log i.e. No sounds files found*/
          }
      }
};
```

Comment: You have a lot of small errors in you code like missing quote or comma but despite that i have answered what resolves the error you have posted

Comment: You don't seem to show where ```this.audioLink``` is defined.  Also, having a data property named 'string' probably not a good idea.  Don't know if JavaScript and/or Vue accept it (never tried it), but could be confusing down the road.

Comment: Thank you, Tim for the advice. Yes this.audioLink is a value return elsewhere in the code which I have not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match returns an array and not a string you know that by logging findings to the console so of course it wont be equal to 'mp3' as a string depending on what the values can be you can do so:

```
 if(this.findings[0] === 'mp3') return console.log('This is a MP3 file');
         else if (this.findings[0] === 'wave') return console.log('This is a Wave file');
         else return console.log('No sound files found'); //you also have a missing quote in this line
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. There was another layer of code that did not log the right values. Now I believe I can use some() or includes() as well :)

Comment: @Drax You're welcome. Yes you sure can and if u need any help we're here